# Combine list elements?

Tags: r, list, element

I've got two long lists A and B which have the same length but contain different numbers of equivalent elements:
List A can contain many elements which also can recur in the same field.
List B either contains only one element or an empty field, i.e. "character(0)".
A also contains some empty fields but for these records there's always an element present in B, so there are no records with empty fields in A and B.
I want to combine the elements of A and B into a new list of the same length, C, according to the following rules:

- All elements from A have to be present in C - including their potential recurrences in the same field.
- If B contains an element which isn't already present in A of the same record it'll be added to C as well.
- But if B contains an element which already is present in A of the same record it'll be ignored.
- If A has an empty field the element from B for this record will be added to C.
- If B has an empty field the element(s) from A for this record will be added to C.

This is an example of how these lists begin:

```
> A  
 [1] "JAMES" "JAMES"  
 [2] "JOHN" "ROBERT"  
 [3] "WILLIAM" "MICHAEL" "WILLIAM" "DAVID" "WILLIAM"  
 [4] character(0)  
...  
> B  
 [1] "RICHARD"  
 [2] "JOHN"  
 [3] character(0)  
 [4] "CHARLES"  
...
```

This is the correct output I'm looking for:

```
> C  
 [1] "JAMES" "JAMES" "RICHARD"  
 [2] "JOHN" "ROBERT"  
 [3] "WILLIAM" "MICHAEL" "WILLIAM" "DAVID" "WILLIAM"  
 [4] "CHARLES"  
...
```

I tried, e.g.:

```
C <- sapply(mapply(union, A,B), setdiff, character(0))
```

But this deleted the recurrences from A, unfortunately:

```
> C  
 [1] "JAMES" "RICHARD"  
 [2] "JOHN" "ROBERT"  
 [3] "WILLIAM" "MICHAEL" "DAVID"  
 [4] "CHARLES"  
...
```

Can anybody tell me, please, how to combine these two lists, preserve the recurrences from A, and achieve the output I desire?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Update:** Machine readable data:

```
A <- list(c("JAMES","JAMES"),
          c("JOHN","ROBERT"), 
          c("WILLIAM","MICHAEL","WILLIAM","DAVID","WILLIAM"),  
          character(0))
B <- list("RICHARD","JOHN",character(0),"CHARLES")
```

Comment: Could you provide the data in such a way that other people could read it in? This would help them to get the example running and they have more time to find a good solution for you. Have a look here on how you could do that: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In particular, have a look at `dput`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and advice! Next time I'll heed it as good as I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your snippte of data, in reproducible form:

```
A <- list(c("JAMES","JAMES"),
          c("JOHN","ROBERT"), 
          c("WILLIAM","MICHAEL","WILLIAM","DAVID","WILLIAM"),  
          character(0))
B <- list("RICHARD","JOHN",character(0),"CHARLES")
```

You were close with `mapply()`. I got the desired output by using `c()` to concatenate the list elements in `A` and `B` but had to manipulate elements of the supplied vectors, so I came up with this:

```
foo <- function(...) {
    l1 <- length(..1)
    l2 <- length(..2)
    out <- character(0)
    if(l1 > 0) {
        if(l2 > 0) {
            out <- if(..2 %in% ..1)
                ..1
            else
                c(..1, ..2)
        } else {
            out <-  ..1
        }
    } else {
        out <-  ..2
    }
    out
}
```

We can refer to the individual elements of `...` using the `..n` placeholders; `..1` is `A` and `..2` is `B`. Of course, `foo()` only works with two lists but doesn't enforce this or do any checking, just to keep things simple. `foo()` also needs to handle the cases where either `A` or `B` or both are `character(0)` which I now think `foo()` does.

When we use that in the `mapply()` call I get:

```
> mapply(foo, A, B)
[[1]]
[1] "JAMES"   "JAMES"   "RICHARD"

[[2]]
[1] "JOHN"   "ROBERT"

[[3]]
[1] "WILLIAM" "MICHAEL" "WILLIAM" "DAVID"   "WILLIAM"

[[4]]
[1] "CHARLES"
```

An `lapply()` version may be more meaningful than the abstract `..n` but uses essentially the same code. Here is a new function that works with `A` and `B` directly but we iterate over the indices of the elements of `A` (`1, 2, 3, length(A)`) as generated by `seq_along()`:

```
foo2 <- function(ind, A, B) {
    l1 <- length(A[[ind]])
    l2 <- length(B[[ind]])
    out <- character(0)
    if(l1 > 0) {
        if(l2 > 0) {
            out <- if(B[[ind]] %in% A[[ind]]) {
                A[[ind]]
            } else {
                c(A[[ind]], B[[ind]])
            }
        } else {
            out <- A[[ind]]
        }
    } else {
        out <- B[[ind]]
    }
    out
}
```

which is called like this:

```
> lapply(seq_along(A), foo2, A = A, B = B)
[[1]]
[1] "JAMES"   "JAMES"   "RICHARD"

[[2]]
[1] "JOHN"   "ROBERT"

[[3]]
[1] "WILLIAM" "MICHAEL" "WILLIAM" "DAVID"   "WILLIAM"

[[4]]
[1] "CHARLES"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution which works perfectly! In addition to that thank you for your helpful edit/update to my question.